# An Urn Simulator

Tags: probability, python

I've written code to simulate drawing without replacement from an urn containing a different numbers of orbs of different colors. It uses random sampling. However, I need to double-check that the "correct" answer I was shown is correct, since my simulator gives something different.

My urn is

- [3 blue, 2 red, 6 green]

I am drawing **4** orbs without replacement

My event is

- [2 blue, 1 green]

This experiment is repeated 100 times, and I need to have **at least** the orbs in the event.
The expected probability is $27.2\%$. This site says there are 81 possibilities and lists 71 of them https://www.mathepower.com/en/urn.php . I can't figure out why I'm getting a probability of above 70%.

1. Is the expected probability accurate?
2. What might be the issue in my code logic (given below)?

logic (psuedo code)

```
run_experiment ==
  set trials = []
  do this 1000 times:
    copy the original Urn
    draw 4 from the urn randomly without replacement (uses Python random.sample(maxint, num_to_take))
    put that result in the trials container/list
  expected = bl bl gr
  matching = []
  things_that_match = [item from expected in item in one trial] e.g. [bl] or [gr] or [bl gr] etc
  make a list (call it eval) containing the 1000 lists of things_that_match
  make a new list containing True if things_that_match == expected, for every item in eval
  sum the trues
  trues/1000 = probability of 
   bl bl gr in 1000 trials of pick 4 from urn [3 blue, 2 red, 6 green] without replacement
```

code: https://gist.github.com/QuantVI/79a1c164f3017c6a7a2d860e55cf5d5b

Comment: I think the probability should be $\frac{87}{330}\approx26.4\%$. If $(b,r,g)$ denotes a draw with the corresponding numbers of blue, red and green balls drawn, there are $\binom33\binom20\binom61=6$ draws of the form $(3,0,1)$, $\binom32\binom21\binom61=36$ draws of the form $(2,1,1)$ and $\binom32\binom20\binom62=45$ draws of the form $(2,0,2)$, for a total of $6+36+45=87$, and there are $\binom{11}4=330$ different draws in total, for a probability of $\binom{87}{330}\approx26.4\%$.

Comment: @VISQL: is the event you are interested the one I which there are at least 2 blue orbs and at least 1 green orb? If do, joriki's has answer seems to be correct.

Comment: Yes at least 2 blue and 1 green. After posting this I believe the issue is in my evaluation of  `things_that`match`. I need to reorder the comparison. Right now it must be the case then even 1 blue existing in a `trial` causes both blues to be brought over as matching.

Comment: @VISQL: I wrote a little R script to simulate (1e4 times) drawing four orbs from the urn (a million times) without replacement and estimate the proportion of times where the event of interest happens. As you can see, this experiment centers around the theoretical probability given by joriki

Answer (score 2):

As noted by joriki, the probability of the event in which at least 2 blue orgs and at least 1 green orb are drawn from sampling, without replacement, 4 orbs is
$$
\frac{\binom{3}{3}\binom{2}{0}\binom{6}{1} + \binom{3}{2}\binom{2}{0}\binom{6}{2}+ \binom{3}{2}\binom{2}{1}\binom{6}{1}}{\binom{11}{4}}=\frac{87}{330}\approx 0.264
$$
Here is a simple R script that simulates the urn an counts the events the OP is describing.

```
    ######  Urn problem simulation
library(parallel)
numCores <- detectCores()
numCores
##
urn <- c(rep("g",6), rep("b", 3), rep("r",2))
k <- 4 # sample size
N <- 1e6 # number of repetitions of game
### check event happens
my_event <- function(urn,k){
  smp <- sample(urn,k, replace = F)
  ifelse(sum(smp =="b") >= 2 & sum(smp == "g")>=1,1,0)
}
## produce N simulations of the sampling and estimate frequency of event
freq_event <- function(urn,k,N){
  sum(unlist(mclapply(1:N, function(i){my_event(urn,k)},
                      mc.cores = numCores)))/N
}
#### simulate experiment N times
p_sim <-  lapply(1:1000, function(x){freq_event(urn = urn, k = k, N = N)})
hist(unlist(p_sim), freq = FALSE)
abline(v = 87/330, col ='red')
mean(unlist(p_sim)) # mean of all simulations
madeian(unlist(p_sim)) # median of all simulations
87/330. # true probability
```

Here is a picture if a histogram with a vertical line along the "real" probability of the event described above.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the code and mathematical representation.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71277539/too-many-copies-poor-comparison-urn-probability-problem/71279128#71279128

Issue was with how matches were being confirmed. I couldn't fix the logic, so I resorted to changing the data structure involved to do the comparison. I was able to an approximate close to 27% (since there are only 1000 trials in the simulation).